# How to translate view with smooth animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I have written a peace of code that perform animation. 
for that i have written a animation file in anim folder

```
my animone.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
     android:fillAfter="true">
     <translate
         android:fromYDelta="0%p"
         android:toYDelta="-5%p"
         android:duration="1500"/></set>
```

and here i apply the animation on the view that is a LinearLayout

```
Animation animate= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.animone);
            subProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//subProfile is a linear layout
            subProfile.startAnimation(animate);
```

so when i run this code . it will suddenly change the position of view without smooth sliding after specified duration.
i want to make it smooth. please help.

----------------here is my complete code----------------
Main Fragment file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.videosapp.Fragments.HomeFragment"
android:background="@drawable/background">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/my_pofile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"   android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dshImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/dashboard"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dashboard"
                android:layout_below="@id/dshImg"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/podcast"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"   android:visibility="gone">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/podcast"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Podcast"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/photo_gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"   android:visibility="gone">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/photo_gallery"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Photo Gallery"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/social"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"   android:visibility="gone">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/social"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Social"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/about_us"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"   android:visibility="gone">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/aboutus"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Know US"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/contact_us"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"   android:visibility="gone">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/contact_us"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Contact Us"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/setting"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"   android:visibility="gone">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/settings"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Settings"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/exit_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"   android:visibility="gone">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/exit"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Exit"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/center_menu"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"   />
    </RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <!--On following  LinearLayout i want to apply animation-->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/my_profile_icon"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="My Profile"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/programs"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/folder_icon"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="My Programs"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

----------------------animation xml file----------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="-100%" /></set>
```

-----------java file in which i apply the animation on click event---------

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.my_pofile:
            animate= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx,R.anim.animone);
            subProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            subProfile.startAnimation(animate);
    break;
    //other cases
}}
```

Comment: Difference between YDelta is very less. Try to increase the duration

Comment: i have already try this but it has no changes.

Comment: Remove interpolator from set and add scale tab. Example:

Comment: <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="150"
        android:pivotX = "50%"
        android:pivotY = "-90%"
    />
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="50%"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="150"
    />
</set>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="-100%" />
```

Comment: it is still just change the location without animation feel

Comment: @SharadGautam one clarification, are you starting animation more than one at a time?

Comment: your code working good for me. Please change the " android:fromYDelta="0%""  to " android:fromYDelta="-100%"" and "android:toYDelta="-100%"" to "android:toYDelta="0%"". Than try again once.

Comment: ok.. now i got it. it is helpful to me and thanx to solve my problem. now it is working well as i want.

Answer (score 2):

Try to

> reduce the resolution or size of all images inside that layout

It will fix the smooth problem.

I also experience this problem and searched on internet but nothing found, then I felt that everything was slow on my layout, then I reduced the resolution and size of all images including backgrounds and you what everything starts working so smooth.

This will fix 100%, It doesn't matter what you use for animation such as AnimationUtils or ObjectAnimator. If it doesn't work smoothly just reduce the resolution of images you are using.

Thanks